# Testing ads for Android when I don't have an Android?

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I need to test the ads work for my mobile game made with Unity, using Chartboost ads, however I don't have an Android to test on, so is there any simulator that I can use that will also display the ads?

Thanks

Comment: This should help - https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200780549-Test-Mode

Comment: Either buy an Android device (or two, such as a phone and a tablet), or do not ship an Android app. **Never** ship a program for a platform that you have not tested **in the way that actual users use the platform**. Users do not use simulators.

Answer (score 1):

You should just get an Android phone/tablet. You should never develop an app for a platform you do not have to test on. You can get this phone from Walmart for $10: http://www.walmart.com/ip/TracFone-LG-L15G-Sunrise-Prepaid-Smartphone/44751495 it should be sufficient enough to test your app(s).